# MySQL order multiple directions using FIND_IN_SET

Tags: mysql

I have a query that orders by `FIND_IN_SET` and then a secondary ORDER field...date_added.

What I am wanting to now do is something like:

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(status, '1,2,3'), date_added ASC
AND
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(status, '4,5'), end_date DESC
```

so I want to order status 1,2 and 3 by date_added `ASC` and the status 4 and 5 by end_date `DESC` but I would like all results for status 1,2 and 3 to be outputted before status 4 and 5.

Can this be done using a single query?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how `ORDER BY` works. You provide all the criteria in the same clause, separating them with commas.

Read the [Sorting Rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sorting-rows.html) chapter for a quick oversight.

**Update:**

You provide neither table definitions nor data samples so it's pretty hard to figure out what you have in mind but I'll try to guess. The [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function returns the index position of the first argument within the second argument:

```
SELECT
    FIND_IN_SET(2, '1,2,3') AS found,
    FIND_IN_SET(4, '1,2,3') AS not_found,
    FIND_IN_SET(NULL, '1,2,3') AS null_needle
```

... returns:

```
found | not_found | null_needle
    2 |         0 |        NULL
```

I understand you want to use part of this information to compose an ORDER BY component (whether the needle is found in the haystack, discarding its position). Then, checking that the returned value is greater than zero should be enough:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN FIND_IN_SET(status, '1,2,3')>0 THEN date_added
        WHEN FIND_IN_SET(status, '4,5')>0 THEN end_date DESC
    END
```

Comment: Yeah I know thats not how ORDER BY works but its the first query I have used using FIND_IN_SET and was checking to see if there is a way to display 1,2,3 first ordered by date_added (as these are active applications) and 4,5 second (as these are ended applications). If there isnt a way I will just write 2 queries.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
  ORDER BY
    IF(FIELD(status, 1,2,3), date_added, '9999-12-31') ASC,
    IF(FIELD(status, 4,5), end_date, NULL) DESC;
```