# checking for specific text in a mysql field inside a query

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a MySQL field with content like this "1,2,3" or "1,6" or just "6". Either a single number, or a comma list.

What I want to do, is a query to find where that field contains say "2", or 2 **and** 6. It would have to be them exactly, so I don't think I can use LOCATE since that would find the first occurrence, not the exact input.

Is there an actual way to do what I want directly in the MySQL query?

I can easily do it in PHP by directly comparing, but I don't want to pull all the rows from the DB to do that.

Comment: read about FIND_IN_SET function

Comment: Storing data like this defeats the whole purpose of using database

Comment: @EatPeanutButter, you are goddamn right!

Comment: *"checking for specific text"* - Integers aren't "text", per se. As stated; you really should normalize your db.

Comment: You will need a combination of CASE and `FIND_IN_SET()` or a subquery. This Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/24849786/1415724 could help shed some light on things and http://stackoverflow.com/q/8148921/1415724